# HTTP and HTTPS endpoint not working in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I cannot add an HTTP endpoint in my WCF Service. The WCF is hosted in a Windows service application. Actually my app.config is like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="Test.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8090" />
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8099" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpBinding" contract="Test.IService"/>
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" contract="Test.IService"/>
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>


  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>

    <binding name="httpBinding">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate
          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          storeName="My"
          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
          findValue="server"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>


  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The service starts, but when i try to access the http or https URL, the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults  thwrows this exception on the browser:

```
**Endpoint: https://localhost:8090/ ----> System.NullReferenceException**
```

How to properly add another endpoint in the app.config?

EDIT:  The code that starts the service:

```
 public class HostService
 {
     public static void Main( string[] args )
     {
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Test.Service));
        host.Open();
        console.writeline("service starts");
        console.Readkey();
        host.Close();
     }
  }
```

Comment: No idea what you mean by "the service starts" or "when I try to access the http or https url".  Show us your client code.  Or do you mean when trying to view the Metadata help page?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch The service starts i mean that the OnStart method executes ok without exception, but when i try to do a Get on both URLS the browser show me that exception. (Yes, when i try to see the metadata help page)

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is from code that is trying to access a instance variable that has not been initialized.  You haven't shown any code; so, it's really hard to guess at what this might be.

Comment: Are you using the [WCF configuration editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009(v=vs.110).aspx)? if you don't, i would strongly recommend it.

Comment: @PeterRitchie basically is that the code (edit the op);

Comment: @elvin actually i dont, but i guess that the problem is in the app.config file. because i can make it work using a single endpoint. the error occours when i add another one.

Comment: That code looks fine, likely something in `Test.Service`

Comment: @PeterRitchie i think the problem is in the app.config, because if i put just one endpoint, one binding (http or https), it works normally. The problem is with both endpoints together